# AWS: How to backup DynamoDB Local tables and import to AWS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I setup DynamoDB Local on a EC2 instance, loaded a dozen of tables with Python API.

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory
```

Now I notice that the tables are stored in memory, and want **to export the data and load to dynamodb web service**. I didn't find any useful functions to export the db tables to a file (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html).

I tried to access the local db through url http://ip:8000, unfortunately it's not working:

```
--2017-08-20 21:49:19--  http://localhost:8000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2017-08-20 21:49:19 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin https://github.com/99xt/dynamodb-schema-migrate which you could use to migrate the schema from to an AWS account. **You can modify it a bit** and use the local schema and use it to migrate the schema.